# Modifying custom post type created by WooCommerce

Tags: custom-post-types, woocommerce-offtopic

I need to modify the `product` custom post type created by WooCommerce. Specifically, I'm trying to set `query_var` to `false` so that `http://example.com/?post_type=product` does *not* redirect to the product archive. Adding the following to `functions.php` doesn't seem to work.

```
add_filter("woocommerce_after_register_post_type", "update_product_post_type");
function update_product_post_type() {
    $args = get_post_type_object("product");
    $args->query_var = false;
    register_post_type("product", $args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this hook fits your cause much better:

```
add_filter ('woocommerce_register_post_type_product', 'my_callback');
function my_callback ($args) {
     $args ['query_var'] = false;
     return $args;
}
```

not tested, but should work.